# Не найден модуль 'gulp-less'

Tags: gulp, less

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    less = require('gulp-less');

gulp.task('less', function() {
return gulp.src('app/less/style.less')
 .pipe(less())
 .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'));
});
```

Собственно содержимое gulpfile.js привёл. lessc style.less style.css работает, gulp, less установлены. Но gulp less в командной строке выдаёт, что не найден модуль gulp-less.

Comment: у вас установлен именно модуль gulp-less? или просто less? в консоли писали npm install -g gulp-less?

Comment: то есть у тебя в папке с проектом есть папка gulp-less и ранее все установилось без ошибок? странно.

Comment: npm install -g less  вводил при установке. попробую gulp-less...НИчего не дало. Таже ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решается вводом в командную строку: `npm install gulp-less  --save-dev`.
Именно `--save-dev` почему то оказалось обязательным дополнением. Всем спасибо.

Comment: `--save-dav` или всё-таки `--save-dev`?

Comment: "--save-dev" измените